# Deployed contract address is getting undefined after few days on private network

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, private-blockchain

I have a private blockchain where I am able to deploy my smart contracts successfully and then I am getting the address of my smart contract which I am storing on my relational db. In geth console when I am trying to access contract method using following code

```
deployedContract = eth.contract(smart_contract_abi).at(contract_address)

deployedContract.myMethod()
```

It's working fine and giving me expected output/result

But after few days when I am trying to access method of contract on those addresses then  I am getting this error:

```
Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number: 
    at L (bignumber.js:3:2876)
    at bignumber.js:3:8435
    at a (bignumber.js:3:389)
    at web3.js:1110:23
    at web3.js:1634:20
    at web3.js:826:16
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:825:12
    at web3.js:4080:18
```

What would be the reason of this error?

Comment: How are you running the node?

Comment: @fixanoid I am using geth client to run my private blockchain using following command: 
 geth --datadir ~/eth-dev/ --networkid 45639 --verbosity 3 --rpc --port 30303 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr “<private IP>”  --rpccorsdomain "http://<private ip>:8080,  http://<private ip>:8000" --rpcapi "web3,eth,personal,net"  --preload "mineWhenNeeded.js"  --nodiscover  --allow-insecure-unlock console 2

Comment: Right, so in plain vanilla geth, you should enable `--gcmode archive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tracing and pruning: By default, state for the last 128 blocks kept in
>   memory.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Tracing:-Introduction

> The block number is mandatory and defines the context (state) against
>   which the specified transaction should be executed. It is not possible
>   to execute calls against reforged blocks, or blocks older than 128
>   (unless the node is an archive node).

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-eth

By default, Geth enables the garbage collection to keep in memory only the latest 128 blocks, I bet you certainly deployed your contract before these 128 blocks were mined.

The **solution** is to use `--gcmode archive`, it disables the garbage collection and keep all the historical state data since the Genesis.