# Why Do I need to deploy contract each time I start a geth node

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I have a simple smart contract that I deploy to my own geth node and it works fine 
but the problem is when I close the geth console and start it again I have to redeply the smart contracts again
Here is the code I am using to start the geth node

```
geth --port 3001 --networkid 5777 --datadir=./node1 --maxpeers=50  --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpca
ddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:3000" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" --allow-insecure-unlock con
sole 2>>eth.log --mine  --miner.gasprice 0   --syncmode 'full'
```

Am I missing something ?????

EDIT:
It is a SimpleStorage Contract, I can get the value after restarting the node but when I try to set it , it doesn't work

EDIT2:
I tried using ganach and it worked perfectly as expected, So I am almost certain that I have a problem with geth

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you ran it as a daemon, when starting Geth, put a `&` at the end of the command.

You should add `--gcmode archive` to avoid a further problem with the garbage collector https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/80062/49141

> The solution is to use --gcmode archive, it disables the garbage
>   collection and keep all the historical state data since the Genesis.

Comment: It didnt work unfourtualtly :(

Comment: Please give us some outputs to help you debug the case. How exactly do you try to invoke your smart contract? 
You can try to open a new terminal and run the below command: `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545`

Comment: I am using truffle to deploy the contract and this is the code (NodeJs) I am using to set the value:


`let encoded = method(...args).encodeABI();
      var tx = {
        gas: "53528",
        gasPrice: "0",
        data: encoded,
        to: contractAddress,
        ...options
      };
      const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
      const result = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signed.rawTransaction
      );`

Comment: I just tried running the code with Ganach and there is no problems at all. 
I dont think the problem is with NodeJs code but with geth settings that I am using